# What is a good algorithm for removing all the edges of a graph that are not part of at least one cycle?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

What is a good algorithm for removing all the edges of a graph that are not part of at least one cycle? Basically I want to "prune all the trees" from an arbitrary graph.

The algorithm that occurs to me off the top of my head does not feel very efficient and is also incorrect:

1. Given a graph `G`, let `C` be a set of edges in at least one cycle. Find a cycle in `G` via a graph traversal and seed C with it edges.
2. For each edge `e` not in `C` but adjacent to a vertex of an edge in `C`, perform a traversal starting at `e` to find a path `P` that terminates in a vertex of an edge in `C`.
3. If such a path `P` exists, add the edges of `P` to `C` and goto 2. Otherwise `e` is the root of a tree, so delete `e` along with all of its children.

The above is inefficient but more importantly the statement "Otherwise `e` is the root of a tree" is incorrect: this algorithm will delete bridges between cycles if both cycles are not already in the set of cycle edges it knows about. To fix this problem you need to only delete `e` in step 3. and then handle connected components that are unconnected from the set C via repeating the entire algorithm on the connected component. This whole approach just feels inefficient and unnecessarily hairy, but I haven't thought of anything better.

Comment: *"removing all the edges of a graph that are not part of at least one cycle"* means [removing all of the bridges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory)). *"prune all the trees"* might mean something different, in which case you need to explain what it means.

Comment: no i do mean removing all the bridges. I just hadnt thought of it that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get a linear-time algorithm by modifying the algorithm due to Hopcroft and Tarjan for finding [articulation points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component).

First, a little bit of theory: for all spanning trees T, for all edges e, there exists a cycle containing e if and only if there exists a [fundamental cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_basis#Fundamental_cycles) with respect to T that contains e. The particular choice of T in the algorithm is a depth-first search tree, which helpfully has only tree and back edges.

The high-level idea behind the code below is, whenever we find a back edge, mark the edges comprising the fundamental cycle as belonging to a cycle. Naively, this yields a quadratic-time algorithm, so what we do instead is have each recursive call return the minimum depth reachable by tree edges followed by a back edge, which we compare against the current vertex's depth to determine whether the edge just traversed is marked.

In Python 3:

```
graph = {
    1: {2, 3},
    2: {1, 4},
    3: {1, 4},
    4: {2, 3, 5},
    5: {4, 6},
    6: {5, 7},
    7: {6, 8, 9, 13},
    8: {7},
    9: {7, 10, 11},
    10: {9, 11},
    11: {9, 10, 12},
    12: {11, 13},
    13: {7, 12, 14},
    14: {13},
}

for v, neigh in graph.items():
    for w in neigh:
        assert v in graph[w]

depths = {}


def traverse(v, depth, parent):
    if v in depths:
        return depths[v]
    depths[v] = depth
    v_low = float("inf")
    for w in graph[v]:
        if w == parent:
            continue
        w_low = traverse(w, depth + 1, v)
        if w_low <= depth:
            print(v, "--", w)
        v_low = min(v_low, w_low)
    return v_low


print("graph {")
for v in graph.keys():
    traverse(v, 0, None)
print("}")
```